# Does "for loop" needs to start at 0 when we are trying to assign the number to array which we get it from user?

Tags: c#, algorithm

I am having a issue which related to loops.

```
            int[] numbers= new int[5];
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter a number: ");
                numbers[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }

            Array.Sort(numbers);

            foreach (int i in numbers)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);

            }
            Console.ReadLine();
```

İf i try to change the `for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)` to `for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)`.
It gives me:System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'.

What is the difference between these two?

1. `int i=0; i<5; i++` => 0->1->2->3->4 Length of array:5
2. `int i=1; i<6; i++` => 1->2->3->4->5 Length of array:5

Comment: You would need to do `numbers[i - 1]` inside your loop, because arrays use a 0-based index.

Comment: As you so eloquently point out, they each produce a different list of numbers.

Comment: if your array has 5 elements the highest index is 4, as array-indices (and lists also) are zero-based. So the second loops last index would be 5 which is not a valid index in the array.

Comment: You can start your *loop* at whatever index you want. But in C# (and most other c-like langauges) arrays are indexed starting with `0`. So the first element of an array will always be `array[0]` and the last element will always be `array[N-1]` (where `N` is the number of elements in the array). So if you want to use the loop's index to access the array elements, you have to be in range from `[0...N-1]` (inclusive)

Comment: To cite from the [C# language specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/arrays): "For a dimension of length N, indices can range from 0 to N – 1 inclusive."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your array has 5 elements the highest index is 4, as array-indices (and lists also) are zero-based.

In order to iterate all elements in an array you should therefor start at zero and stop at `Length - 1`. In your case that means go from zero to 4 as in your first loop.

The second loop starts at 1 and goes to 5. As 5 is not a valid index in the array (remember, it has 5 elements, but the highest index is 4), you get the exception.

Afterall you can also define for-loops from any arbitrary start-index. For example you can reverse the loop:

```
for(int i = array.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--) { ... }
```

Or you can take just the second through the fourth item:

```
for(int = 1; i < 4; i++) { ... }
```

You can also iterate the numbers from -5 to 10, that are completely unrelated to any array:

```
for(int i = -5; i < 10; i++) { ... }
```

So in short: a for-loop does not assume any specific start. However when iterating collections you have to ensure you stay within their bounds which are zero-based.